# What is different between: android.support.design.button.MaterialButton and com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

Tags: android, material-design

Android Studio 3.3.2

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

In my new Android project I want to use new android Material button.

I found 2 packages for this:

```
android.support.design.button.MaterialButton 

com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
```

What is a differences between them? And what package I must use?

Answer (score 4):

Google is moving from the Design library (`android.support.design`) to [the Material Components for Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) (`com.google.android.material`).

Roughly speaking:

- If you are using AndroidX libraries, you probably want the Material Components for Android
- If you are using the older Android Support Library set of artifacts, you probably want the Design library

The role of `MaterialButton` is about the same in the two libraries, though the Material Components for Android offers more theme-level control IIRC.

Comment: `com.google.android.material` v1.0.0 = `android.support.design` v28.0.0. You can follow development of Material Design Components for Android here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases

Comment: I use AndroidX libraries. So as result I need to use "com.google.android.material". Is I'm right?

Comment: @Alexei: "Need" is a strong word, but I would recommend using `com.google.android.material`.